# How to rename column after pandas groupby.size()?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, series

I have a large excel file in the format as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':["a","b","c"],'Id2':["a","b","z"],'Amount':[10, 30,50]})

print(df)
```

I want to calculate the following formula.

```
x=(df.groupby(["Id","Id2"]).size())/len(df)
print (x)
```

How can I add a name to the right column? (0.3333...)
After adding the name to the column, I want to save this as .txt format.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html), followed by [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to convert to a dataframe:

```
x = x.rename('Value').reset_index()

print(x)

  Id Id2     Value
0  a   a  0.333333
1  b   b  0.333333
2  c   z  0.333333
```

Then export to txt / csv as you would normally with a dataframe:

```
x.to_csv('out.txt', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jpp. You are a life saver!